# How do I open a CAB file on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, archiving, file-format, cab

How do I open a CAB file on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) supports them too.

Comment: Thanks. I prefer that one over StuffIt. It is open source and does not ask for an admin password to install.

Comment: You can check what gets installed (check out Pacifist), but likely the password is needed only because of the location of the install.

Comment: @Nerdling: Probably. I really wished the standard installers offered a way to install just into the current user account, rather than system-wide.

Answer (score 3):

The [Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html) failed to open my particular CAB file ("error decrunching"), so I tried another pretty open-source app, called [keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/doc.php), which could do it.

There is also a cross-platform command-line tool that works: [cabextract](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/).

Answer (score 3):

In my case, neither *The Unarchiver* or *cabextract* were able to extract the .cab file, but the latter pointed me to *unshield* (https://github.com/twogood/unshield), which unpacked the file successfully.

Both *cabextract* and *unshield* are available in Homebrew (`brew install unshield`).

The syntax to unpack a file named `data.cab` with *unshield* is:

```
unshield x data.cab
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice tool to know about.  Tested this with a `.cab` that was embedded in an MSI and unfortunately neither this nor any of the other solutions worked (the utility states it's not an Installshield cabinet file, which is correct it's not) :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the freeware [StuffIt Expander 2010](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/system_disk_utilities/stuffitexpander.html).
It supports over 30 archive file formats, including CAB.

Answer (score 0):

Using unshield (brew install unshield):

Most install packages contain 3 files:

> data1.**hdr**, data1.cab and data2.cab

Which can be extracted with:

```
unshield x data1.hdr
```